# unzipping Large zip files on Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

I am working on a Github Action pipeline, I simply want to perform the follwoing steps

1. Download 6 zip files the least of which the size is 500 MB and the most is 7GB
2. Extracts the files to a direcory
3. Run a build on a Dockerfile
4. push required image to an azure container image registery

The following is my build script but I keep gettting the following error

> error: End-of-centdir-64 signature not where expected (prepended bytes?)
> (attempting to process anyway)
> warning [./bnk.zip]:  152 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
> (attempting to process anyway)

See build file below

```
# This workflow will build a Java project with Maven
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/building-and-testing-java-with-maven

name: Build Temenos Image From Dockerfile

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest 
    steps:
    
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 11
    - name: Download Temenos bnk
      run: wget -q http://example.com/artifactory/example-repo-local/bnk.zip
    - name: Download Temenos jboss
      run: wget -q  https://example.com/temenos-containers/jboss.zip
    - name: Decompress bnk
      uses: TonyBogdanov/zip@1.0
      with:
         args: unzip -qq ./bnk.zip -d ./R23
```

Comment: A [standard runner](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#standard-github-hosted-runners-for-public-repositories) has 14 GB storage, so depending on the total size of you files, you might be running into limits here.

Comment: @BenjaminW. total size is 11.1GB

Comment: Have you looked at this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54904/unzip-error-end-of-central-directory-signature-not-found)?

Comment: yes @Azeem I was looking for a fastjar for GitHub actions but I did not see any

Comment: @DaviesTobialex, when you say you don't see, you mean the command is not available by default? If that's the case then, you need to install `fastjar` or maybe `7z` using apt in previous step of github. The apt installation commands are given in the the thread shared by Azeem

Comment: @Kartoos I was able to get Fastjar to unzip. but I am faced with another issue. seems the zip file is corrupt 
> jar xvf bnk.zip
> java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found

but it's not conclusive yet. from frying pan to fire.

Comment: @DaviesTobialex Make sure the zip is not corrupt and you are able to unzip it locally, before running anything on the github you can verify that at least you are able to unzip it locally using whatever command tool you wanna use. You can try to use `7z` as well to unzip, lastly are you sure total size (downloaded + extracted) will be <= 14 GB?

Comment: @Kartoos (downloaded + extracted) would be more than 14 GB, more like 23 GB. I guess I may have to change my approach, build the image locally and then move the image from my local PC to a private repository.. lol... I would think more on this